# all tables used by a stored procedure and all sps that use a particular table - recursive cte

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dependencies

I am working on a script that gives me a list of tables that use a specific stored procedure.

It also works on all tables used by a stored procedure.

on the example below, all stored procedures that use the table 'ProductItemDetailsDenorm'

```
USE US15WINMPRODUCT
GO

DECLARE
      @sp_name nvarchar(128) -- NULL shows all stored procedures that use the table @table
     ,@table   nvarchar(128)

SELECT 
      @sp_name = NULL
     ,@table   = 'ProductItemDetailsDenorm'


            ;WITH stored_procedures AS (

                SELECT 
                schema_name(o.schema_id) as proc_schema,
                o.name AS proc_name, 
                schema_name(oo.schema_id) as table_schema,
                oo.name AS table_name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
                FROM sysdepends d 
                INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id=d.id
                INNER JOIN sys.objects oo ON oo.object_id=d.depid
                WHERE o.type = 'P'

            )

            SELECT proc_schema,
                   proc_name, 
                   table_schema,
                   table_name 
            FROM stored_procedures
            WHERE [row] = 1
            AND ((@sp_name IS NULL) OR (proc_name = @sp_name)) AND ((@table IS NULL) OR (table_name = @table))
            ORDER BY proc_name,table_name 

            --sp_help 'sys.objects'
```

This gives me the list below (partial):

[image]

The question, the bit I am struggling with is the following situation:

what if inside the stored procedure SP1 there is a stored procedure SP2 that uses the table @MyTable?

I want that to be listed as well.

I thought the solution could be:

> there should be a recursive cte to cater for procedures inside
>   procedures that might use the table @table

but so far I have failed to implement it.

recursive CTEs should have 2 parts: anchor and UNION ALL.
how would I apply these two in the current CTE?

any hints?

[image]

Comment: Try not to use `sysdepends`. You should be using `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

Comment: Something like this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072445/query-to-recursively-identify-object-dependencies

Comment: Or even Example 4 on this article : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/

Comment: on sql server 2005 unfortunately there is no sys.sql_expression_dependencies

Comment: Please always tag with the version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following script comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072445/query-to-recursively-identify-object-dependencies)
and it has worked fine for my tests 
using sql server 2005 (stored procedures inside other stored procedures)

example of output:
[image]

this is the code:

```
--=========================================================================

--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072445/query-to-recursively-identify-object-dependencies

--== utlGetAllDependentObjectsRecursive - Uses recursive common table
--==     expression to recursively get all the dependent objects as well
--==     as the child objects and child's child objects of a 
--==     Stored Procedure or View or Function.  can be easily modified to 
--==     include all other types of Objects


--Wrote this Stored Procedure below which RECURSIVELY lists all 
--the dependent child objects and child's dependent objects and child's child...etc. 

--The input parameter can be Stored Proc, User Function, View. 

--Can easily be altered to get a Unique List of Column 5, regardless of what Level the Object 
--was called and how deep and by which object.

--COLUMNS

--UsedByObjectId - The parent object that uses the dependent object
--UsedByObjectName - The name of the parent object
--UsedByObjectType - Type of the parent object (P,V,FN)
--DependentObjectId - The child object the parent uses
--DependentObjectName - Name of the child object
--DependentObjectType - Type of the dependent child object (P,V,FN, U)
--Level - How deep, the nested recursive level which the object is used

--=========================================================================



USE US15WINMPRODUCT
GO

DECLARE
      @sp_name nvarchar(128) -- NULL shows all stored procedures that use the table @table
     ,@table   nvarchar(128)

SELECT 
      @sp_name = NULL
     ,@table   = 'ProductItemDetailsDenorm'




   -- Supports Stored Proc, View, User Function, User Table
declare @PARAM_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR(500)

select @PARAM_OBJECT_NAME = 'sp1'
--select @PARAM_OBJECT_NAME = 'ProductItemDetailsDenorm'


   ; WITH CTE_DependentObjects AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
        b.object_id AS UsedByObjectId, 
        b.name AS UsedByObjectName, b.type AS UsedByObjectType, 
        c.object_id AS DependentObjectId, 
        c.name AS DependentObjectName , c.type AS DependenObjectType
        FROM  sys.sysdepends a
        INNER JOIN sys.objects b ON a.id = b.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.objects c ON a.depid = c.object_id
        WHERE b.type IN ('P','V', 'FN') AND c.type IN ('U', 'P', 'V', 'FN') 
    ),
    CTE_DependentObjects2 AS
    (
       SELECT 
          UsedByObjectId, UsedByObjectName, UsedByObjectType,
          DependentObjectId, DependentObjectName, DependenObjectType, 
          1 AS Level
       FROM CTE_DependentObjects a
      WHERE a.UsedByObjectName = @PARAM_OBJECT_NAME


       UNION ALL 


       SELECT 
          a.UsedByObjectId, a.UsedByObjectName, a.UsedByObjectType,
          a.DependentObjectId, a.DependentObjectName, a.DependenObjectType, 
          (b.Level + 1) AS Level
       FROM CTE_DependentObjects a
       INNER JOIN  CTE_DependentObjects2 b 
          ON a.UsedByObjectName = b.DependentObjectName
    )

    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM CTE_DependentObjects2 
    ORDER BY Level, DependentObjectName
```